# ifelse add a calculated field in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Hi everyone I am trying to add a calculated field into a data frame in R using several conditionals at the same time.

I have the following data frame called df

```
     ID A                 AA          AAA        AAAA   AAAAA
1     1 a                 no            57         10     100.0%
2     2 b                 no            32          7      70.0%
3     3 c                yes            30          7      70.0%
4     4 d                 no            52          7      70.0%
```

And I want to add a new field called Z with the following conditions that basically add 25%  in case is true

```
ifelse(df$AA=="yes",0.25,0) + ifelse(df$AAA<30,0.25,0) + ifelse(df$AAAA>4,0.25,0)
```

So I added the following code

```
df$Z<-as.data.frame(ifelse(df$AA=="yes",0.25,0)+ifelse(df$AAA<30,0.25,0)+ifelse(df$AAAA>4,0.25,0))
```

but I got the following error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Z, value = list(`ifelse(df$AA=="yes",0.25,0)+ifelse(df$AAA<30,0.25,0)+ifelse(df$AAAA>4,0.25,0)` = numeric(0))) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 200
```

I guess I am trying to translate an excel formula into R which is

```
=IF(C2="yes";25%;0)+IF(D2<30;25%;0)+IF(E2>4;25%;0)
```

Best Regards

Comment: To make your question easily reproducible please put your dataframe into a useable object for example like this: df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! This will help those who want to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last column, if you have `'%'` sign then remove it before doing comparison.

```
df$AAAAA <- as.numeric(sub('%', '', df$AAAAA))
df$Z <- with(df, ifelse(AA=="yes",0.25,0) + ifelse(AAA<30,0.25,0) +
                 ifelse(AAAA>4,0.25,0))
```

You can also do this without `ifelse`

```
df$Z <- with(df, (AA == 'yes') * 0.25 + (AAA < 30) * 0.25 + (AAAA > 4) * 0.25)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, I tried the code and adds the calculated field, but when I call the data frame ```df```, the name of the last column that should be is AA and not Z and surprisingly the dataframe has two columns with the same name. When I call ```df$Z```, (which means that the column exist), list the computed values with an index [1,] with square brackets and not like the classic dataframe index

Comment: @mauron Try using different name instead. `df$Z1 <- with(df, (AA == 'yes').......rest of the code`

Comment: Are you using the same code which I have put above or are you adding something more to it?

Comment: Yes Ronak, but I guess is better to make another question, as there are several lines of code and is another topic

Comment: Sure, you can make another question for it then. If this answer helped you please consider to accept the answer by clicking on checkmark next to vote button so that it can be marked as solved.

Comment: I did mark the answer but It says that I do not have enough reputation to do so, I am sorry as your solution was excellent.